# RSI results different than in TradingView (coded in Python)

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

It's been days I spent trying to code (and search) a python function to get RSI that match TradingView results but without success (I'm new to Python).

The closest results I get for RSI is this function, but still different (and the fact exponential is used, sometimes result is pretty close, sometimes there is a pretty huge difference):

```
def rsi_tradingview(ohlc: pd.DataFrame, period: int = 14, round_rsi: bool = True):

    delta = ohlc["close"].diff()

    up = delta.copy()
    up[up < 0] = 0
    up = pd.Series.ewm(up, alpha=1/period).mean()

    down = delta.copy()
    down[down > 0] = 0
    down *= -1
    down = pd.Series.ewm(down, alpha=1/period).mean()

    rsi = np.where(up == 0, 0, np.where(down == 0, 100, 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))))

    return np.round(rsi, 2) if round_rsi else rsi
```

My code looks like this:

```
pairs = ["BTCUSDT", "PONDUSDT"]

def get_historical_candles():
    record = client.get_historical_klines(pair, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "3 hour ago UTC")
    myList = []
    
    try:
        for item in record:
            n_item = []
            int_ts = int(item[0] / 1000)
            n_item.append(float(item[4]))  # close
            myList.append(n_item)
            
    except Exception as error:
        debug_logger.debug(error)
        
    new_ohlc = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['close'])
    
    return new_ohlc

def rsi_tradingview(ohlc: all_candles, period: int = 14, round_rsi: bool = False):

    delta = all_candles.diff()

    up = delta.copy()
    up[up < 0] = 0
    up = pd.Series.ewm(up, alpha=1/period).mean()

    down = delta.copy()
    down[down > 0] = 0
    down *= -1
    down = pd.Series.ewm(down, alpha=1/period).mean()

    rsi = np.where(up == 0, 0, np.where(down == 0, 100, 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))))

    return np.round(rsi, 2) if round_rsi else rsi

for pair in pairs:
    all_candles = get_historical_candles()
    test_rsi = rsi_tradingview(all_candles, 14, False)
    test_rsi_final = test_rsi[-1]
    print(test_rsi_final)
```

I compare results with `tradingview_ta` this way, that give correct results (I can't just use this function to get RSI because I need the RSI to calculate StochRSI):

```
for pair in pairs:   
    test = TA_Handler(
        symbol=pair,
        screener="CRYPTO",
        exchange="BINANCE",
        interval=Interval.INTERVAL_5_MINUTES
    )
    print(test.get_analysis().indicators["RSI"])
```

If this can help, here are the codes on TradingView to get RSI and how is calculated RMA

```
# RSI 
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
              

# RMA
plot(rma(close, 15))
//the same on pine
pine_rma(src, length) =>
    alpha = 1/length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])
plot(pine_rma(close, 15))
```

Please guys, help me to find what is wrong. :(

And Thank you by advance! Thanks for reading!